# How do i figure this array/loop out

Tags: arrays, loops

Here is my code. my objective is to print the current array bonusScores, but make the new values assigned to bonusScore[i] = bonusScores[i + 1] and leave the last element in the array at 40. i have two problems. my for loop makes the variable i go past the maximum number of elements the array can hold and my second problem is setting the last element to 40. Any ideas on how one would do this? Thanks!

```
public class StudentScores {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
      int[] bonusScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int i = 0;

      bonusScores[0] = 10;
      bonusScores[1] = 20;
      bonusScores[2] = 30;
      bonusScores[3] = 40;

      for(i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++){
         bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i + 1]; 
      }

      for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
         System.out.print(bonusScores[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();

      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind guys I figured out my code problem thanks guys all i had to do was change

```
for(i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++){
         bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i + 1]; 
      }
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE-1; i++){
         bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i + 1]; 
      }
```